# Как разделить строку на части по n символов через rejex

Tags: java, массивы, регулярные-выражения, строки

Я написал вот такой код. Он делит введенную строку на части по **n** символов. Но тут я подумал: "А зачем мне такой большой код, если возможно сделать тоже самое, но через **text.split(*rejex*)** и просто записать в массив ?". Правда я так и не нашел регулярки, которая будет отбирать n символов по очереди. Я только недавно познакомился с регулярками и пока только изучаю эту тему.
**14:40 UPD:** Я нашел регулярку `String[] words = text.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");`, вот только мне надо указать не точное число, а мою переменную n. Можно ли вставить переменную в регулярку ?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println(main.test("Hello, World", 2));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> test(String text, int n) {
        ArrayList<String> substringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int symbolRange = n;

        if (n <= 0) {
            return substringList;
        }
        for (int i = 0; symbolRange <= text.length(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                substringList.add(text.substring(0, n));
            } else if (symbolRange + n <= text.length()) {
                substringList.add(text.substring(symbolRange, symbolRange + n));
                symbolRange += n;
            } else if (symbolRange != text.length()) {
                substringList.add(text.substring(symbolRange, symbolRange + (text.length() - symbolRange)));
                symbolRange += n;
            } else {
                return substringList;
            }
        }
        return substringList;
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
[He, ll, o,,  W, or, ld]
```

Comment: *если возможно сделать тоже самое* - а кто сказал, что возможно?

Comment: @zed а разве нельзя ? Я думал можно как то указать диапазон регулярками и все.

Comment: @zed только что внес update в свой вопрос. В нем я указал регулярку, которая делит на части. Но она работает только с числом. Делит правильно

Comment: `"(?<=\\G.{" + Integer.toString(n) + "})"`

Comment: @zed да, это работает. Спасибо большое. Залейте ответ и я помечу его как решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разве что так?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



 public class tr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 2;
            String a = "Hello, World";
            Pattern compil = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G.{"+Integer.toString(n)+"})");
            String []i = compil.split(a); // split делит строки на подстроки
               for(String word:i)
                    System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, как это работает? Почему, если я делаю `split(" ")` то пробелов на выходе не будет, а в случае с этой регуляркой все символы присутствуют?

Comment: данное РВ говорит машине: ?-(1-0) совпадений, в данном случае .-любой символ{n}раз, <=\\G предлалает машине продолжить поиск совпадений с конца предидущего совпадения

Comment: метод  сплит удаляет из строки то что в нем указано , в вашем случае " " и делит строку на подстроки в этом месте